# Extending modular arithmetic to vectors, using only integers.

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic, numerical-linear-algebra

I want to extend modular arithmetic to vectors over integers such that if

$\vec{q} = \vec{p} + M \vec{n}$

implies

$\vec{q} \equiv\vec{p} \mod  M$

where $M$ is a square matrix whose columns are linearly independent vectors.
The key part here is that I want to be able to do this computationally using only integer arithmetic.

If I relax that constraint, the problem is straightforward by extending to the rationals. Here $M$ is invertible so

$M^{-1}\vec{q} = M^{-1}\vec{p} +\vec{n}$

then I can test the equivalence of the elements $\mod 1$ (do they differ by an integer).

The problem I have is in a computational implementation, where doing exact inversions of $M$ will be expensive and challenging, I am wondering if there is a way of testing the equivalence of the two vectors as described using only integer arithmetic.

Comment: Seems that you are just implementing the arithmetics in the quotient space $V/\text{im}(M)$, where $V$ contains all the $p$ and $q$. Testing equivalence of two vectors then becomes checking if a vector lies in $\text{im}(M)$, which can be checked by many efficient methods. One method would be Gaussian elimination. There has to be more efficients ones, but I'm not familiar with it.